# How does Google judge page performance if audience is from one specific region & server is also in same region

Tags: google-search, ranking, page-speed, google-pagespeed

I want to know how does Google Judge page performance, let us our server are located in India as our audience is from India and page speed over all is fine based on FF developer tools & Chrome ..

```
Total 68 Request
2.80 MB/2.38MB transferred
Fisnish4.62s
DOMContentLoaded:2032s
Load 2.80s

Total Request 94 (including external request)
```

and page performance goes down when we access website from EU, US etc... Which location does Google take into consideration for page performance as there are lot of article on Internet where its is mentioned page performance is important for search engine and page speed should load under 3 seconds for better ranking etc..

Since i dont know from where Google will index or crawl our website pages which can effect page performance, can anyone shed some light on this

Answer (score 9):

Google measures speed from the US.   However, for SEO, Google doesn't actively penalize sites unless they are *very* slow.   Unless your pages (without JS, CSS, and images) takes more than 7 seconds from the US, you have nothing to worry about.

Google will notice if your users find your site slow.  If your page isn't usable for your visitors in three seconds, it may indirectly hurt your rankings based on user behavior.   That means that in your local country, your pages including JS, CSS, and images should be downloaded and rendered in 3 seconds.

If you can make your site fast enough for local users, you won't have any trouble with the site being fast enough for Googlebot, even when it crawls from the US.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to download all the assets within 3 seconds. I've open my chrome dev tool and in network setting I see it's take 4800 ms to open this page on ignite mode. I think 3 seconds is about DNS resolve, not about complete painting of specific webpage. Youtube taking 7000 ms.

Comment: Well the page needs to be usable within 3 seconds. You can lazy load things after that. I try to keep my site to 800 milliseconds.

Comment: In Google search console, I've added 3 sites, and in all sites I see only 50-200 milliseconds for downloading page in [crawl stats](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-stats). So I think Google might using some thing else to download/crawl any webpage super fast. Is there any major difference between your page loading time vs google crawl downloading page time? I think that's the right answer, how much Google take downloading your page is what Google use it on their algorithm page.

Comment: @Goyllo Stephen is referring to the first context meaningful paint that can be fetched by a crawler or any user agent. The best rule of thumb is to keep the loading time as less as possible to use the page.

Answer (score 3):

Google know that latency is different across region. And Google bot mainly comes with USA IP. So if you think your server should be on USA for faster rendering, then sorry it doesn't work like that. Page should be load under 3 seconds, that's right but it doesn't mean it should be render completely within 3 seconds. When you open YouTube, it is open in only 1-2 seconds that means it's resolve DNS within 1 seconds, but it's take 10-20 second for complete painting. See here [how browsing works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Performance_best_practices_for_Firefox_fe_engineers#Get_familiar_with_the_pipeline_that_gets_pixels_to_the_screen).

Google collect each user data from their device, may be it is already include in their terms and service, when they use Google search. So they collect pagespeed data from various sources. It's not like Google bot is from USA, so your server must be in USA for faster pagespeed. Think about users, they use users pagespeed data, if your all users open your site faster, then Google will somehow collect those data. So focus on users experience.

Also one more note that, Google search algorithm doesn't gives you higher score if your site is load in 2.3 seconds and your competitor site in 2.9 seconds. You both will get same score, john mueller said that once. [Google have decent article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals)s and course on udemey(link given in their own articles) on how to improve more for better user experience. Read them, there are so many articles on that. If you improve your codes, you might get better result than geo based pagespeed test.

Comment: I had similar understanding but so many article video event from some prominent SEO guys focus also on improving page speed to make it load under 3 seconds in such a way that it created doubt in my mind recently. appreciate your insight into topic